# C API mysql Add columns if they don't exist incorrect syntax

Tags: mysql, c

I have searched everything I could ) Truly. But I can't find the correct way to add new columns only after checking if the column doesn't exist. I am writing a program in C.
Here is what I am doing, and I can't find my mistake in syntax. I will be very grateful for your help! I get an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use`

```
//create buffer to store the query
char buff[1024];
//store query in the buffer                
snprintf(buff, sizeof buff, "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = '%i' AND TABLE_NAME = '%s' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '%s') THEN ALTER TABLE `%s`.`%s` ADD COLUMN `%i` INT; END IF;", value1, table, database, database, table, value1);
```

**EDIT**

I am editing the post to show what I am trying to achieve.
Using nested if statement in the main function, I have created the database and the table, and have populated the table with column names; my code is designed in a way that all functions are interrelated: only if connection is established, the program calls "create database" function; only if database is created, the program calls "create table" function; only if the table is created and initially only two columns are added (id and Names), the program calls the function to alter table in order to add other columns.

I do so because I need a for loop to loop those additional column names, which were created previously by my previous C program.
So the table should look like this:

```
id   name   1988   1977   1966   1955
1    name1  value  value  value  value
2    name2  value  value  value  value
3    name3  value  value  value  value
```

Each time the program is called, each function checks if database exists, then it is not created from scratch, if table exists, it is not created, and now I am stumbled on how to check of columns exist, because if they do, I get an error and the program can't move on.

Comment: Don't use `sprintf()` use prepared statements and parameters through `MYSQL_BIND` structure. Also, I am worried as to why will you add columns if they don't exist, that looks like a design error.

Comment: IF can only be used inside a procedure, trigger etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219714/check-if-column-exists-before-alter-table-mysql can help

Comment: The correct way to add a column is `ATER TABLE table ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS name TYPE;`.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi I have tried this syntax, but it didn't work; got the syntax error as well. Then I searched everywhere, and have found out that this syntax is not yet implemented in mysql.

Comment: @Vitale I just tried it and it works perfectly, although I am using archlinux which brings MariaDB instead of MySQL but I am not aware of MariaDB implementing this feature while MySQL not.

Comment: @Vitale you did improve your question now, my recommendation is that you read about SQL databases and relational databases concepts, in particular what a schema is and how to properly design one for your particular problem. I have added an example below in my answer so that you get started, bottom line **DO NOT USE A SQL DATABASE WITH A DYNAMIC SCHEMA**, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: One reason why it's so hard to do it the way you want is because it's not meant to.

Answer (score 0):

To add a column you can do it like this

```
snprintf(
    buff, 
    sizeof buff, 
    "ALTER TABLE `%s`.`%s` ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS `%s` `%s`", 
    database,
    table, 
    column_name, 
    column_type
);
```

Note that in your format string there is a `%i` that doesn't look right.

After giving you the answer, because this is what you asked for, I want to say that adding a column in code like that looks like a bad sign. SQL databases are pretty static in their structure, you should never need to add or remove columns from it. If you have to, then there is a problem either in the database design or the way you are handling it.

According to the comments below you need something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `names` (
    `name` VARCHAR(128) PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `year` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- Or the required type (FLOAT perhaps?)
    `value` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    -- All names MUST come from the `names` table
    CONSTRAINT `name_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`name`) REFERENCES `names` (`name`),
    -- Allow only one entry per `name`/`year`
    CONSTRAINT `entry_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`name`, `year`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And then you can insert each name in the `names` table, and one entry per year in the `entries` table, you can have the combinations you want and you can query all years for a given name

```sql
SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE `name` = ?
```

Creating a database schema dynamically is wrong, it's just against the whole idea of a schema, a database has a schema so you can write queries an rely on them working, the language is called **Structured Query Language** for a reason.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried it, and got the syntax error. I will try it again of course. I can't use anything but %i in that one instance, because the value I am passing is an integer, and all columns have numbers as names. For example, they will be named: 789 or 1298

Comment: @Vitale that seems very unreliable. Can you tell me why are you trying to do this? This is a very bad idea. It appears that you have a [xy problem](http://www.xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: I have tried it again; used the version you have - the one without closing `;` before double quotes in ALTER TABLE statement; and also the version with those `;`. Same error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS `1988` INTEGER' at line 1`

Comment: Oh, I will be truly grateful if you explain what is wrong with this choice. My goal is to populate the table with values I have computed using C. I have: (1) row names that go vertically from top down (name1, below it goes name2, below name3, etc, making a column of names); (2) then, as each name represents a row, I populate each row with values, and each value corresponds to a certain year; and this is why my columns have integer names - they are years. I will update my original post and will try to show how the table should look like.

Comment: You need to create a database that allows you to do that instead, a year should not be a column but instead a value of a column in a given row. This really doesn't make sense, at least it doesn't make sense to use a SQL database for this. If you want, tell me more about it to see if a can help you, my email is iharob@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am learning C, I got used to flexibility and to the ability to use dynamic approach.

Comment: @Vitale Note that this is actually more flexible, but SQL databases are like that.