# Check if a column exists while reading a database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

In my database I made two different tables for objects, let's say OBJECT, and ORIGINAL_OBJECT(in French, in example it is Repere), the only difference between them is ORIGINAL_OBJECT has not any column where I save the modifies made.

I have a function that gets me all the fields :

```
public Repere Select_detail_repere(string query)
        {
            Repere det = null; ;
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                IDataReader dataReader = ExecuteReader(query);
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    det = new Repere();
                    det.Name = (dataReader["DET_NOM"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.Modifies = dataReader["MODIFICATIONS"].ToString().Trim();
                    det.Profil = (dataReader["DET_PRF"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.Matiere = (dataReader["DET_MAT"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.GroupeProfil = (dataReader["DET_GRP_PRF"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.Longueur = double.Parse(dataReader["LONGUEUR"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.Largeur = double.Parse(dataReader["DET_LARGE"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.Hauteur = double.Parse(dataReader["DET_HAUT"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.Poids = double.Parse(dataReader["DET_PDS"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.Angle1 = double.Parse(dataReader["ANG_AME_1"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.Angle2 = double.Parse(dataReader["ANG_AME_2"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.AngleAile1 = double.Parse(dataReader["ANG_AILE_1"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.AngleAile2 = double.Parse(dataReader["ANG_AILE_2"].ToString().Trim());
                    det.PercageString = (dataReader["PERCAGE"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.ScribingString = (dataReader["SCRIBING"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.Mark = (dataReader["MARK"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.ContInt0 = (dataReader["CONT_INT"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.ContExt0 = (dataReader["CONT_EXT"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                    det.Revision = (dataReader["REVISION"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
                }
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            return det;
        }
```

I use the same function for both OBJECT and OBJECT_ORIGINAL.
But when I want to read my OBJECT_ORIGINAL, I meet an error that says the field doesn't exist (obviously).

I already met the same problem in other situations, as this function will only work if I use `SELECT *` (if I don't read all columns this will return an error).

Until now the only way I found to solve it is using try/catch (in the catch I will apply a default value, `ID=-1` for example), but I feel as it is not a very correct solution, and looking for another way to do that.

Comment: Did you read the MSDN documentation of `IDataReader`?

Comment: just did it now, but didn't help on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the column `MODIFICATIONS` exists in the datareader, as you don't know it on forehand.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader?view=netframework-4.7.2) of Microsoft I found a method called [`GetSchemaTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader.getschematable?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_IDataReader_GetSchemaTable).
It will give you a datatable that describes the column metadata. So you could check that table to see if there is a column with the name `MODIFICATIONS`.
I would put that check in a different method so it doesn't clutter the code in your `while` loop that much.

**OR**

You could check this question on StackOverflow [Check for column name in a SqlDataReader object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373230/check-for-column-name-in-a-sqldatareader-object)  which has a shorter solution to your problem.
I think that's even a nicer and easier solution, but I found it (with a simple google search) after I had almost completed my answer above. So that's why I give you both solutions (and also to help you a little with the MS documentation, which I pointed to in my comment)

Comment: Ok, I think I understood. With the method given in stack link I launch the method "HasColumn" (only once of course), then an ifelse will solve the problem.

Comment: Well, regarding stack link, I was not able to understand how it works. But, thanks to you I found the link to GetSchemaTable, then DataColumnCollection, and I think I found something, it is not as "short" as I expected, but it makes the trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to give as the query you use as well but I think you can use `IF COL_LENGTH('table_name','column_name') IS NOT NULL` in your query.

Comment: Query very simple : SELECT * FROM table1 will work, SELECT * FROM table2 will not work as the column "MODIFICATIONS" doesn't exist. It is not in the query I need to put a condition, but when I read the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql stored procedure and do the checking inside on it.
check it here.
[check if column exists before ALTER TABLE -- mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219714/check-if-column-exists-before-alter-table-mysql/11740960)

Comment: I saw that already, and that's not what I want, what he says on that post is to create the column if it doesn't exist, and I don't want to touch it.

Comment: Ahh sorry for not understanding it. Its quiet sensitive database manipulation ehh..

Answer (score 0):

This question can be quoted as "Duplicate", I found the answer on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader)

```
public Repere Select_detail_repere(string query)
{
    Repere det = null; ;
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        IDataReader dataReader = ExecuteReader(query);
        bool containsModification = CheckIfDataContains(dataReader, "MODIFICATIONS");
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            det = new Repere();
            det.Name = (dataReader["DET_NOM"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
            if(containsModification)
            {
                 det.Modifies = dataReader["MODIFICATIONS"].ToString().Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                 det.Modifies = "";
            }
            det.Profil = (dataReader["DET_PRF"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
            det.Matiere = (dataReader["DET_MAT"] ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim();
            ...
         }
         this.CloseConnection();
      }
      return det;
  }
  public bool CheckIfDataContains(IDataReader dataReader,string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (dataReader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Instead of using a `for` loop you are using the `contains` method which goes through all columns.
You could shorten the method by just doing `return columns.Contains(columnName)` instead of the `if` statement, but that's just what you like.

Comment: thanks, in fact return columns.Contains(columnName) is better, just edited, thanks for your feed-back. p.S : how do you "grey" your comments?

Comment: You can use backticks for that, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for help on formatting.

Comment: Well just "unaccepted" answer, as I noticed only now the code is not working, in fact {columns.Contains(columnName)} returns always false

Comment: `Contains` could be case sensitive. Also be sure column names are not duplicate, it will return false. See Microsoft Documentation

Comment: still looking, for now all my column names are "ColumnName", "ColumnOrdinal", "ColumnSize" etc... seems I am reading columns definition instead of their names.

Comment: ok found it, my code is wrong, and found an answer on stack, will edit my answer now

Comment: Good it works now. I see you ended with the code mentioned in the link I posted in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373230/check-for-column-name-in-a-sqldatareader-object (which is OK)

Comment: really? it is the link you gave me?(just checked, and it is...) well I made it really bad then, don't know why I remember I looked your link and didn't understand anything... or I read really bad, or in that time I understood something better who knows... anyway thanks for Ur help (will then put your answer as the good one, until they put my question as duplicate ^^)